# RoR – Can I check the type of an object and its associations in a single query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Imagine I have this query right now:

```
if basket.is_a?(FruitBasket) && basket.things.joins(:fruit).exists?(fruit: { type: Apple.name })
  # Does something
end
```

Would it be possible for me to simplify them into one query without the `&&` operator? I have been trying to do so but can't really figure it out.

Comment: `basket.is_a?(FruitBasket)` is not a query. It's just asking if the object `basket` is an instance of the class `FruitBasket`. No db query involved.

Comment: Can you share the db schema for the involved models?

Comment: It's probably possibly to check something like `basket.type == 'FruitBasket' && ...` instead of a class-check? But even then, it's not making a second query; the `basket` object is already loaded in memory.